# Linking external dynamic libraries with CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake

**TL;DR**:
*I have compiled a library and put everything needed from it in one directory (i.e. .lib, .dll and .h files). I am working on a project in a different directory using Clion. I need the project to include those headers, and to link to those libraries to be accessible at runtime. I do not need a true cross-platform CMake file just yet: I just need the build and run to work on my machine for the time being.*

I have looked at all the other posts on the topic, but have not been able to find a clear and concise solution that I can replicate. I am hoping to find the definitive answer.

Some background: Since working in Java and Python for the last few years, I am returning to developing in C++. I am limited to working in a 64-bit Windows environment at the moment. My dev stack is CLion + Cygwin64 + Cmake + Clang. We will be using the POCO library so I've decided to try it out. I built the 64-bit libraries locally, and placed the resulting install in a convenient location. I need to link these libraries into a different project, but I am having no luck as I am new to CMake and have yet to fully understand its behaviour.

Functionally, my directory structure is as follows:

```
C:/somedir/Poco
           ├─── bin        # e.g. PocoFoundation.dll
           ├─── lib        # e.g. PocoFoundation.lib
           └─── include    # e.g. Poco/Poco.h, Poco/Component/component.h

C:/otherdir/project
           ├─── main.cpp
           └─── CMakeLists.txt
```

I've tried to make this run in several ways. The following results in the external headers being included and the build succeeding, but the executable fails on runtime with a "... undefined reference to Library::Component::Class::method()" exception:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(project ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(POCO_PREFIX      "C:/somedir/Poco")
set(POCO_INCLUDE_DIR "${POCO_PREFIX}/include")
set(POCO_LIB_DIR     "${POCO_PREFIX}/lib")
set(POCO_LIBS "${POCO_LIB_DIR}/PocoFoundation.lib" "${POCO_LIB_DIR}/PocoUtil.lib")

target_include_directories(project PRIVATE "${POCO_INCLUDE_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(project "${POCO_LIBS}")
```

I have also tried the `find_packages` approach following [the instructions here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries), with a find module [found here](https://github.com/astahl/poco-cmake/blob/master/cmake/FindPoco.cmake), adjusted for my needs (i.e. slightly different library naming, using only the release configuration). However, this failed to build in the first place, with the find script exiting on line 176, even though I confirmed via message() that cmake is looking for the right files in the right directories.

I understand that this should be relatively simple, but despite that I have not been able to find any straightforward documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple ways in Windows to provide an executable the paths for the DLLs to load. IMHO all are somehow complicated or error prone except one: Store all DLLs in the same directory like the executable itself. This also prevents that the executable will accidentally load/bind a DLL with same name which is found first but actually not compatible. (I fighted with this in the past when I used GTK+. Trying to solve dependency problems, I found for my surprise a lot of distinct gtk DLLs from various applications on my HD - and most of them incompatible to my own application in development.)

Comment: @scheff Thank you for the quick input. I have gathered there is no straightforward way to do this, but I don't understand why exactly it is so complicated on Windows. Building and running the same source code in Ubuntu 14.04 has been absolutely painless. Building via Visual Studio 2017 involved some tinkering with the project settings, but was relatively straightforward as well. Clion + Cmake are giving me grief however.

This project will involve other third party dependencies, which we will be extending and rebuilding as well, so I would like avoid storing the dll's in the project.

Comment: Whether dependencies to DLLs can be resolved or not depends on how you "put" them onto your system. If you installed them by a setup they might have added its own location to the `PATH` or the registry but if you just unzipped an archive they, of course, didn't. The former may be found be your application without additional actions the letter not (if not storing them in the same dir. like the EXE). So, is the result of former (the setup with PATH) better? No! Remember my GTK+ story. It might happen that the same DLL becomes multiply available and in distinct binary versions which might be...

Comment: ...incompatible to each other. The system will choose the first matching DLL (i.e. by name) and this need not to be a binary compatible. Btw. MS invented a new thing to solve this: side-by-side installation. No idea, how this works. (You may google it if you want to find out.) The only way out is what I mentioned first: Put all DLLs needed due to dependencies in the same dir. like your EXE. Btw. this was not my own invention but a hint I found somewhere in GTK+ doc. It seems that you and me are not the first ones which stumbled over this...

Comment: @Scheff Thank you for the clear explanation! From that perspective it does make sense to bundle as many resources as possible with the executable. Side-by-side assemblies seem like a powerful tool to ship and avoid version conflicts. I am curious to see how these methods will develop vis-a-vis the trend toward containerization, especially in performance and resource sensitive use-cases